# Binding Control DataContext to DataType of DataTemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `DataTemplate`. I want to bind the `DataContext` of my control to the `DataType` of the `DataTemplate`:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type kitchens:KitchenRule}">
    <controls:KitchenChartView
        DataContext="{Binding}"/>
```

However, in the constructor of my control code behind, the `DataContext` is always null?

```
KitchenRule kitchenRule;

    public KitchenChartView()
    {
        if (this.DataContext is KitchenRule)
        {
            this.kitchenRule = DataContext as KitchenRule;
        }
    }
```

Comment: At the time of the constructor being called bindings are not yet resolved.

Comment: Is there a way I can use a DataContextChanged event to set my KitchenRule in the code behind? this.DataContextChanged += (sender, args) =>
            {
                if (this.DataContext is KitchenRule)
                {
                    this.kitchenRule = DataContext as KitchenRule;
                }
            };

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your DataContext at design time, to avoid it being null:

```
<UserControl
...
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=kitchens:KitchenRule, 
IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"/>
```